# In App Billing NullPointerException on getBuyIntent(...)!

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to use InAppBilling in my application . I have use the similar code previously and it worked but now I faced an error! My logcat:

```
08-19 16:19:38.096: E/AndroidRuntime(27034): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3594
08-19 16:19:38.096: E/AndroidRuntime(27034): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-19 16:19:38.096: E/AndroidRuntime(27034):    at com.taygon.tick_one.Buy$2.run(Buy.java:101)
08-19 16:19:38.096: E/AndroidRuntime(27034):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

And when I double click 3rd line it highlights `getBuyIntent(...)` function. Here is my code:

```
IInAppBillingService mService;

ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mService = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
    }
};

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mServiceConn != null) {
        try {
            unbindService(mServiceConn);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1372) {

        String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            try {

                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                Toast.makeText(Buy.this, "Thank you",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(Buy.this,
                        "Error Happend!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        else
            Toast.makeText(Buy.this, "Not Compeleted",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}






public void buy_package() {
            try {
                Bundle buyIntentBundle;
                buyIntentBundle = mService
                        .getBuyIntent(
                                3,
                                getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
                                "Product Serial Number",
                                "inapp",
                                "My App RSA Code");

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle
                        .getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");

                startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),
                        1372, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0),
                        Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));

            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

Comment: which line in `Buy.java 101` is?

Comment: Buy.java is my activity that has in app billing codes.

Comment: line number 101 is .getBuyIntent(

Comment: paste the code where you are initializing `mService`.

Comment: I have updated that. Please see my updates.

Comment: I don't know if I am right, I guess `onServiceDisconnected` is getting called. So try to debug the code or add a system out println code above `mService = null` line. And check if `mService` is `null` or not.

Comment: How can I a add a system out println? Please help me .It is a part of my project .

Comment: `System.out.println("onServiceDisconnected called, value of mService is null");` add this line above `mService = null;` and run the code. Check console if you see this message then it means `onServiceDisconnected` is called.

Comment: Having the same problem, did you find a fix?